# Why is nothing showing up on one of my panels?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, imageicon

I've got a method that is supposed to create my UI, and it works. However the lowest panel (named panel currently) isn't showing my icons, nor will it show the text when I just change the label name to a simple text ex"Bed6a".

Can someone clue me in here?

```
public static void showUI() {

int bedCount = getBedCount();
bedCount = bedCount - 5;

Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
int xSize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth());
int ySize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight());

ImageIcon maleBed = new ImageIcon("Images/Male.png");
ImageIcon femaleBed = new ImageIcon("Images/Female.png");
ImageIcon emptyBed = new ImageIcon("Images/Empty.png");
ImageIcon logo = new ImageIcon("Images/Medicalistics_Logo.png");
ImageIcon mlogo = new ImageIcon("Images/Medicalistics_Logo.png");

JFrame window = new JFrame("Ft Lauderdale");
window.setVisible(true);
window.setSize(1049, 710);

window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
window.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
menuBar.add(mnFile);

JMenuItem mntmPrint = new JMenuItem("Print");
mnFile.add(mntmPrint);

JMenuItem mntmExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
mntmExit.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {

    }
});
mnFile.add(mntmExit);
window.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

Panel infoPanel = new Panel();
infoPanel.setBackground(Color.orange);
infoPanel.setBounds(371, 0, 671, 160);
window.getContentPane().add(infoPanel);
infoPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setBounds(0, 161, 1041, 499);
window.getContentPane().add(panel);
SpringLayout sl_panel = new SpringLayout();
panel.setLayout(sl_panel);

JLabel lblBeda = new JLabel(emptyBed);
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, lblBeda, 10, SpringLayout.NORTH, panel);
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, lblBeda, 10, SpringLayout.WEST, panel);
panel.add(lblBeda);

JLabel lblBeda_1 = new JLabel(emptyBed);
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, lblBeda_1, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, lblBeda);
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, lblBeda_1, -374, SpringLayout.SOUTH, panel);
panel.add(lblBeda_1);

JLabel lblBeda_2 = new JLabel(emptyBed);
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, lblBeda_2, 84, SpringLayout.SOUTH, lblBeda_1);
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, lblBeda_2, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, lblBeda);
panel.add(lblBeda_2);

JLabel lblBedb = new JLabel(emptyBed);
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, lblBedb, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, lblBeda);
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, lblBedb, 39, SpringLayout.EAST, lblBeda);
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, lblBedb, 76, SpringLayout.EAST, lblBeda);
panel.add(lblBedb);

JLabel lblBedb_1 = new JLabel(emptyBed);
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, lblBedb_1, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, lblBeda_1);
panel.add(lblBedb_1);

JLabel lblBedb_2 = new JLabel("Bed3B");
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, lblBedb_2, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, lblBeda_2);
panel.add(lblBedb_2);

JSeparator separator = new JSeparator();
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, separator, 28, SpringLayout.EAST, lblBedb);
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, lblBedb_2, -28, SpringLayout.WEST, separator);
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, lblBedb_1, -28, SpringLayout.WEST, separator);
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, separator, 10, SpringLayout.NORTH, panel);
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, separator, -3, SpringLayout.SOUTH, panel);
separator.setBackground(Color.RED);
separator.setOrientation(SwingConstants.VERTICAL);
panel.add(separator);

JLabel lblBeda_3 = new JLabel("Bed4A");
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, lblBeda_3, 84, SpringLayout.SOUTH, lblBeda_2);
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, lblBeda_3, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, lblBeda);
panel.add(lblBeda_3);

JLabel lblBedb_3 = new JLabel("Bed4B");
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, lblBedb_3, 39, SpringLayout.EAST, lblBeda_3);
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, lblBedb_3, 0, SpringLayout.SOUTH, lblBeda_3);
panel.add(lblBedb_3);

JLabel lblBeda_4 = new JLabel("Bed5A");
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, lblBeda_4, 10, SpringLayout.WEST, panel);
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, lblBeda_4, -74, SpringLayout.SOUTH, panel);
panel.add(lblBeda_4);

JLabel lblBedb_4 = new JLabel("Bed5B");
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, lblBedb_4, 0, SpringLayout.SOUTH, lblBeda_4);
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, lblBedb_4, -28, SpringLayout.WEST, separator);
panel.add(lblBedb_4);

JLabel lblBeda_5 = new JLabel("Bed6A");
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, lblBeda_5, 160, SpringLayout.WEST, panel);

sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, lblBeda_5, 0, SpringLayout.SOUTH, lblBeda);
panel.add(lblBeda_5);

JLabel lblBeda_6 = new JLabel("Bed7A");
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, lblBeda_6, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, lblBeda_1);
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, lblBeda_6, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, lblBeda_5);
panel.add(lblBeda_6);

JLabel lblBeda_7 = new JLabel("Bed8A");
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, lblBeda_7, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, lblBeda_2);
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, lblBeda_7, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, lblBeda_5);
panel.add(lblBeda_7);

JLabel lblBeda_8 = new JLabel("Bed9A");
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, lblBeda_8, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, lblBeda_3);
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, lblBeda_8, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, lblBeda_5);
panel.add(lblBeda_8);

JLabel lblBeda_9 = new JLabel("Bed10A");
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, lblBeda_9, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, lblBeda_4);
sl_panel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, lblBeda_9, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, lblBeda_5);
panel.add(lblBeda_9);

panel.setVisible(true);
```

}

Comment: Don't use setBounds(). The layout manager will determine the size/location of a component. Don't use "Panel". With Swing you should use `JPanel`. I never use SpringLayout since it is too complicated. I suggest you try another layout manager so you don't have to worry about all the hard coded values. If you are using an IDE to generate the code then get rid of the IDE and write the layout code yourself.

Comment: I removed the bounds, and it just makes the application full screen, which is fine. However, until I resize the window manually (using the maximize button) nothing shows up in the gui.

Comment: The `setVisible(...)` statement needs to be executed AFTER all the components have been added to the frame.